# AngularJS: Expression value for REST API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I create several DOM-elements on my website using AngularJS ng-repeat, for example image objects that need to be loaded dynamically. I iterate through a JSON object and for each element in the JSON object the correct HTML-output should be:

```
<img src="/myRestImageService/{{image.name}}">
```

Taking a closer look at my REST service on the server side, it turns out every now and then the value of the AngularJS-expression {{image.name}} does not resolve but will be appended cleartext. Of course, this leads to error prone REST-calls like:

/myRestImageService/%7B%7Bitem.name%7D%7D

What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User angular directive `ng-src` instead of `src` ,so try 
 
`<img ng-src="/myRestImageService/{{image.name}}">`

Here is further documentation for ng-src :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Excellent, that helped! Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

when you use *angular variable* in your *DOM* element you should use angular directives so use `ng` or `data-ng` before `src`.

so you should use

```
<img data-ng-src="/myRestImageService/{{image.name}}" alt="Description"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone says, use ng-src

This prevents the browser from attempting to make a call using the angular string.  Once processed it'll put the "string" into the src attribute and the browser will handle the rest.

[ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) is a directive specifically made for this purpose.